# Yodlee Aggregation REST API error message

Tags: yodlee

I invoked a REST API function and got back the response:

{"errorOccurred":"true","exceptionType":"com.yodlee.core.IllegalArgumentValueException","referenceCode":"XXXXXXXXXXXXX","message":"Multiple exceptions encapsulated within: invoke getWrappedExceptions for details"}

I don’t see anything in the Yodlee documentation describing how to “invoke getWrappedExceptions.”

How do I determine what’s wrong with the REST request I sent that received this response?

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the request here? In case if you are a customer then please raise a Service Request using Yodlee Customer Care tool.

Answer (score 0):

IllegalArgumentValueException comes when the parameter for the corresponding REST API is not passed correctly. Please go through the [API reference section](https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference) for the particular API and validate all the parameters you are passing.

If you are using either of the addSiteAccount1 or addItemForContentService1 and getting this exception,  then please call either getSiteLoginForm or getLoginFormForContentService and use the correct value form these calls to form the request for addSiteAccount1 or addItemForContentService1.

Comment: It would be tremendously helpful if the error message at least identified which parameters have been passed incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I will raise it as an enhancement for our APIs but for now, you will have to check the exception description from the document and validate your parameters against the documentation.